# Taxonomy Extra Meta

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, metabox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding Custom Field to Taxonomy Input :Panel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/adding-custom-field-to-taxonomy-input-panel)

I created a custom post type with a taxonomy associated.
When I add new item for my taxonomy, I get name, slug and description. I want a new field in there, because I also need to add a image in my taxonomy.php file

This is what I use to get the name and description:

```
<?php
if(isset($wp_taxonomies)) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
    if($term) {
        echo '<h1>'.$term->name.'</h1>';
        ?> <img class="alignright" alt="<? echo $tax_term->name; ?>" src="<? echo $term->description; ?>" /> <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Can you tell my how can I hook a new textarea in my custom taxonomy and get-it in my taxonomy page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
add_action("manage_posts_custom_column", "my_custom_columns");
add_filter("manage_edit-[POSTTYPE]_columns", "my_new_columns");

function my_new_columns($columns)
{
    $columns = array(
        "image" => "Image"
    );
    return $columns;
}

function my_custom_columns($column)
{
    global $post;
    if ("ID" == $column) echo $post->ID;
    elseif ("image" == $column) echo 'default_value';
}
```

Then you should be able to use `$tax_term->image` to show it.

This is untested but see [this article](http://kovshenin.com/archives/custom-post-types-in-wordpress-3-0/) for more info. Also look into the hooks  [manage_edit-post_type_columns](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_edit-post_type_columns) and [manage_posts_custom_column](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column) You may also want to edit the code to show an image upload field instead of a text field but it at least gets you started.