# create a "add icon" field in taxonomies page

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, metabox

Similar to [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/adding-custom-field-to-taxonomy-input-panel) but not quite, I have a Wordpress theme with free Fontawesome already installed and I wish to add a field in the "create Categories" box where I could type in and choose an icon to assign to each CPT's taxonomy. Such a field was available in another theme but not on this one where I do have the possibility to add icon but from the media library instead.
Is there a way to add it? Some snippet?

UPDATE: I found exactly [the plugin that does the work](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-icons/), however it showed a problem: it doesn't output the icon because the theme function to pull the image from media library seems to take priority. The question is if there's a filter to eliminate that theme function (given the fact that I need to find where it is nested)

Comment: Adding meta boxes to your taxonomies isn't all that difficult if you're comfortable building your own plugin.  You said you're using a third-party theme though, so how are you going to modify the theme's output so that the categories show up?  Are you using a child theme?  I can help you with something relatively simple if you're comfortable putting together a plugin.

Comment: I'm not a coder so I'm not comfortable in writing a plugin... I mean, I know how it is structured but I cannot write functions. I do use a child theme and a snippets' plugin to add extras. I have actually seen some tutorials about adding metaboxes, but in this case the problem is that of taking over the theme's metabox (I'm still searching where its driving code might be located)